# Uber SDK in android

Tags: android, sdk, uber-api

I am trying to add an Uber 'request a ride' button in my android application. In my gradle build file I have added the following line:

```
compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.0'
```

Automatically Android studio asks to sync the gradle files as they have changed. After this I get 500+ errors with my project but when I remove the  dependency it all goes back to normal.

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

The module gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.myuberapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.sembozdemir:ViewPagerArrowIndicator:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.2.9'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.0'
}
```

The full set of errors:

[Error file is here](http://txt.do/5b7qc)

Comment: Posting some of the errors would help.

Comment: Hey, I worked on this SDK. Can you post your gradle script and the errors and I'll help you debug?

Comment: @tsmith I added the errors and gradle file. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've past the 64k limit and should enable [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

The majority of those "errors" are actually warnings that gradle seems to be grouping together. Check the last couple lines of the error for the exact message.

**In your build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**And in your manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Separately:**

Since the Uber SDK isn't that large, another suggestion to delay multidex is to only the use the Play services libraries you actually need.

For example, instead of

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

You could use just cloud messaging (if that is the component used).

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
```

[See more here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I did you a combination of the two. I first set up the MultiDex and then cleaned up my compiles in the gradle file.